# Use gdalwarp to crop area with simple coordinate system

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm new to GIS and trying to cut image with gdalwarp

I need image projected like google map and I need to input coordinates of area of interest in latidute longitute system, like:

from 45.3 10.2 to 45.8 10.5

Source file as this info:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (501592.500000000000000,5215807.500000000000000)
Pixel Size = (15.000000000000000,-15.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  501592.500, 5215807.500) (  9d 1'15.54"E, 47d 5'44.79"N)
Lower Left  (  501592.500, 4979992.500) (  9d 1'12.71"E, 44d58'24.14"N)
Upper Right (  733807.500, 5215807.500) ( 12d 4'42.99"E, 47d 3'15.77"N)
Lower Right (  733807.500, 4979992.500) ( 11d57'47.40"E, 44d56' 5.69"N)
Center      (  617700.000, 5097900.000) ( 10d31'14.58"E, 46d 1'28.40"N)
Band 1 Block=15481x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I'm trying with command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=32N +datum=WGS84" -te 45.1 10.1 46.1 11.1 -ts 4096 4096 -overwrite source.tif output.tif
```

But the -te parameter has not read as coordinate. The output file is full black and as this info:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (45.000000000000000,11.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000244140625000,-0.000244140625000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  45.0000000,  11.0000000) (  4d30'41.97"E,  0d 0' 0.36"N)
Lower Left  (  45.0000000,  10.0000000) (  4d30'41.97"E,  0d 0' 0.32"N)
Upper Right (  46.0000000,  11.0000000) (  4d30'42.01"E,  0d 0' 0.36"N)
Lower Right (  46.0000000,  10.0000000) (  4d30'42.01"E,  0d 0' 0.32"N)
Center      (  45.5000000,  10.5000000) (  4d30'41.99"E,  0d 0' 0.34"N)
Band 1 Block=4096x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: there is not enough information in your question for anyone to be able to answer. explain please. What is the image you are starting with? What is the coordinate system of that image? What coordinate system do you want the output to be in? What is the program you are using gdalwarp in? What version?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you have to swap the coordinates. It should be longitude latitude order.

45°E is not within UTM 32N (and within the extent of your source file), but 10°E will be.

Apart from that, the [manpage](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) says:

```
-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:
     set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS by default, or in the SRS specified with -te_srs) 
-te_srs srs_def:
     (GDAL >= 2.0)
```

So you have to set the target extent in the **target** projection, since you may not be running GDAL 2.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. For navigation-like map could use **EPSG:4326** that work with normal latitude/longitude coords system

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te 12.47302 37.55202 13.90263 38.67817  -ts 1024 1024 input.tif output.tif
```